# Protecting a certain feature with a password

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently creating a game where if a player wants to play a certain level, the player has to provide the password to unlock it. I have the following code right now:

```
var password;
var psd= "abcdefg";
password=prompt('Enter the Passcode: ');
if (password==psd){functions}
```

However, I want to make it so that the input text for password is masked. I also want to make it just a tiny bit more secure so that the players won't be able to cheat themselves by inspecting the JavaScript code. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: User will still be able to get the password from your JS source code.

Comment: The only proper way to do password protection is on server side.

Comment: Don't use `prompt`. Create a html dialog, with a password field.

Answer (score 2):

The way I would do it is with a an html dialog, containing buttons and a password input element.  E.g.:

```
<input type="password" id="pwd">
```

This will give you the black-dots you are referring to.

There is very little you can do to secure the password on the client-side without using a hash function and server-side run-time communication.  If you are carrying out the comparison on the client then at some point the password, or the hash, must be present on the client.

Answer (score 1):

You could use MD5, it is a hash algorithm.

Check this out: http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5/

Comment: Gah! MD5 is **NOT** a secure hash algorithm

Comment: It would work fine for this scenario. The level password could be hashed and stored on the page, then the use password could be hashed on input and compared.

Comment: Edited and updated :)

Comment: Note that [MD5 databases](http://www.google.com/search?q=md5+database) exist. You may want to append a random [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) to your password before hashing it. Also consider re-hashing the MD5 output, say, 1000 times or so to make it slower to crack by brute force. (Maybe also consider using a more secure hash, like SHA-2 or SHA-3, although MD5 should still be more or less OK for this particular purpose.)

Comment: But nevertheless, the user will be able to inspect the client-side functions which will be executed in the code if the password matched.

Answer (score 1):

for the security bit, you could hash the correct password an then create the hast of the input and check if those are equal (for example md5 or sha1) (as posted in the answer before md5 (and i think sha1 too) are not "secure" but i doubt anyone would put so much effort in unlocking this level

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by giving `<input type='password' >`

But this doesn't make sense as you are explicitly storing the password in java script. Anyone who views the source can get the password. The only way is to store the password in a database and use AJAX to check whether the password is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Regardless of what you do, the password will be view able especially if everything is on client side.

But If it's just obfuscating the password it could be done in so many ways.

For example :

```
var psd = "\u0041\u0042\u0043\u0044\u0045\u0046\u0047".toLowerCase();  // abcdefg
```

Or use the functions in JS itself:

```
btoa("abcdefg");      // "YWJjZGVmZw=="

atob("YWJjZGVmZw=="); // "abcdefg"
```

Answer (score 0):

One idea to obfuscate your password a little more is to generate user specific passwords, depending on some data that you might have of them, like e-mail address and nickname:

```
var email = "xyz@abc.com";
var player = "zoidberg";

function createHash(text) {
    //a function that returns a unique hash, i.e. MD5 or others (depending on your needs of security)
}

//this is the password that you show the user when he finished a level
var pw = createHash(email + player).substring(0, 8);

//this is the internal hashed passwork
var hashedPw = createHash(pw);

//a function that validates a password that was entered by the user
function validate(userInput) {
    if (createHash(userInput) === hashedPw) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Of course, if someone looks at your javascript code, he can still figure out the entire logic behind the password creation but at least you don't have your password written down in clear letters. And as an additional plus, different players can't just share their password because each player has an individual one.

That being said, the safest way is of course to move the whole authentification process to the serverside. Safe your passwords somewhere in your database and make AJAX calls to verify a password that was entered by the user.